# Animation increase height

Tags: android, android-animation

What I'm doing now is a sound wave and to do it I have created an animation that increase the height

please see this picture

[image]

so my problem is that the animation works and it increase the height however I wanted to make it reverse grow

Hope you can help me thank you

So my code is here

```
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.sound_wave);
view.setAnimation(animation);
view.animate();
animation.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a way to solve your problem while continuing to use an animation resource. I would instead use `ObjectAnimator`.

Here's how to build your same animation using `ObjectAnimator`:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1f, 0.5f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.start();
```

You also have to add an attribute to your `View` in whatever layout file defines it. In my case, I made my view `400dp` tall, so I added this:

```
android:transformPivotY="400dp"
```

This will cause the scale animation to be anchored at the bottom of the view (since its pivot is equal to its height).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you sir.
this is exactly what I needed.